# Exchange 2010 allows outside access to network files

Tags: exchange-2010, file-sharing, security

One of our users discovered by accident he could access our network files from his smartphone while at home. No VPN needed. He was sent an email with an internal link to a network share on his android. When he opened the email and clicked on the link, he could browse our files while at home.

Looking at the access logs, the connection to the share and files he accessed came from our mail server (Exchange 2010). We have no sharepoint servers running at all, and certainly not on the Exchange server.

What is this function/feature called, and is it possible to turn this function/feature off? Should I turn this off?

Answer (score 3):

It's called "Computer File Access" or "Direct File Access", but I think this only available through OWA, and not through other means (i.e. directly from the Smartphone from the built-in-email-client)

> Direct file access lets users open files that are attached to e-mail
>   messages and files that are stored in Windows file shares. You can
>   manage direct file access for Microsoft Office Outlook Web App in
>   Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 for both public and private computers.
>
> By default, public computer direct file access is enabled for new
>   installations and upgrades of Outlook Web App. Therefore, when users
>   in your organization select This is a public or shared computer or
>   This is a private computer on the Outlook Web App sign-in page, they
>   will be able to access files that are attached to e-mail messages.

For details, see here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124232(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: +1 - was just about post this exact answer and link.

Comment: In this case, he is directly accessing from the [Android] smartphone, using the built in email client. He is using the Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync choice though, so apparently that counts as OWA. The link is a good read, but fails to mention directory browsing, which he is able to do. I don't have a problem with accessing files attached to the email, but browsing diretories (and being able to change directories) sounds like a nice security hole to me.

Comment: He's an authenticated user on an allowed device using https - where's the hole?

Comment: Mobile phones are high theft targets, and the password is remembered. According to my local PD district robbery division, almost all the robberies so far in 2014 are mobile phones. The slang term for that is "apple picking" BTW.

Comment: @user2891127 Sounds like you need to look into MDM (Mobile Device Management) software.  They all suck (like AV), but allow you to push out settings to all the mobile devices you let access the network, to prevent this very type of thing in the event a phone is stolen.

Comment: Exchange also has it built in - force password policy, allow remote wipe.

Answer (score 0):

MichelZ pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

There is a feature in Exchange 2010 SP2 and SP3 (but not SP0 or SP1???) called [Windows File Share Integration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430762%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx#fileanddataaccess). This is what enables directory browsing. The article doesn't tell you how to change it, nor do the ones it links to, but I figured it out.

Open Exchange Management Console -> drill down to server configuration -> Client Access -> Exchange ActiveSync (middle tab) -> right click on the name (default website in my case) properties -> Remote file servers tab. From here, you can allow or deny access.

Comment: The feature was introduced in Ex 2007, but wasn't re-introduced into 2010 until SP2.